# Avoiding build dependency on QuickCheck when declaring an Arbitrary instance

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, quickcheck, build-dependencies

Assume I have a Haskell module named `Foo`, defined in `src/Foo.hs`. Assume also that `Foo` exports a type `Bar`.

Now I want to write unit tests for `Bar` (for the whole `Foo` module, actually), so I throw a couple of QuickCheck properties into `test/FooTest.hs`; but hey, now I need to define an `Arbitrary` instance for `Bar`.

And there's the rub: in `-Wall -Werror` mode, `ghc` requires instance declarations to appear in one of two places: in the same file where the type is defined, or where the class is defined. But I don't want to clutter my `Foo` module with a build dependency on QuickCheck, and I obviously cannot add an instance of `Bar` to QuickCheck.

So how do I make my datatype an instance of `Arbitrary`, for the purpose of unit testing only, without introducing a dependency on QuickCheck for users of my module and without tossing`-Wall -Werror` out of the window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the test suite, create a newtype which wraps `Bar` and define the `Arbitrary` instance for the newtype.

Comment: Argh, will the boilerplate never end?! ;)

Comment: @Arek'Fu The boilerplate might be reduced by exploiting safe coercions as needed.

Comment: @chi, it's still an awful lot of noise, and you'd need to fall back on unsafe coercions for GHC 7.6 if you support that. I don't see how it's worth the trouble for a test suite.

Answer (score 4):

Try `ghc -Wall -Werror -Wno-orphans` for the test module.

Not exactly perfect since it will disable the warning for other orphan instances, but I believe it's the closest we can get at the moment.

Having a "suppress this warning in the next line" pragma would also be nice.

Comment: Almost all of the arguments for avoiding orphans don't apply to test suite executables. This option is much more attractive to me than using CPP to make my module contain different code when included in the tests than for production builds.

Comment: @Ben, in some cases that's already necessary. Test code may need access to otherwise non-exported constructors and functions. One option is to export all of those unconditionally, but in a large and mature module that doesn't do so, that requires careful testing for potential performance changes. The inliner treats exported and non-exported bindings differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally define a `TESTING` CPP macro when you're compiling the test suite. This lets you avoid orphans but only incur the dependency when you use it. You can see a similar use of such a macro in the `containers` package, but that package currently uses orphan instances for the specific purpose of adding `Arbitrary` instances to the test suite. I may change that soon.